# Android / Getting ID corresponding to notification that is dismissed

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

Consider the following piece of code.
I am trying to print 'Notification #[id] is dismissed' corresponding to the id of the notification that is dismissed.
Why does if I dismiss notification #1, both 'Notification #1 is dismissed' and 'Notification #2 is dismissed' are printed at the same time?
Why does if I dismiss notification #2, 'Notification #0 is dismissed' gets printed and it is given that there is no notification corresponding to value of 0 for id?

Where am I doing wrong?
What is the way to correct it?

MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button b1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alert(1);
                alert(2);
            }
        });
    }

    void alert(int id)
    {
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle("Notification Example");
        mBuilder.setContentText("Notification #" + Integer.toString(id));

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);

        // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        Intent onCancelIntent = new Intent(this, OnCancelBroadcastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent onDismissPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, onCancelIntent, 0);
        mBuilder.setDeleteIntent(onDismissPendingIntent);
        onCancelIntent.putExtra("id", id);
        sendBroadcast(onCancelIntent);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // notificationID allows you to update the notification later on.
        int notificationID = id;
        mNotificationManager.notify(notificationID, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

OnCancelBroadcastReceiver.java

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class OnCancelBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Do your logic here
        int id = intent.getIntExtra("id", 0);

        Toast.makeText(context, "Notification #" + Integer.toString(id) + " has been dismissed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/notify" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">NotificationExample</string>
    <string name="notify">notify</string>
</resources>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.samsung.notificationexample">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".OnCancelBroadcastReceiver"
            android:label="OnCancelBroadcastReceiver">
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

By the way, NotificationCompat.Builder is deprecated in later versions of Android (starting from what Android version?).
Is there any other alternative for it?

Comment: `NotificationCompat.Builder(context)` is deprecated, you should always use a `NotificationChannel`, and the Compat builder ignores it if the android api running the app doesn't support NotificationChannels.

Comment: The `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`, which has a value of `134217728` is an important flag. Replacing `PendingIntent onDismissPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, onCancelIntent, 0);` with `PendingIntent onDismissPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, onCancelIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);` seemed to resolve this issue for me.

Comment: By the way, the statement of `sendBroadcast(onCancelIntent);` is not needed.